# php stacking string query

Tags: php

I am trying to nest if statements based on a query string, but it isnt working

query string

```
index.php?list&page=1
```

php

```
if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] == 'list') {
  if ($_GET['page'] == '1') {
    echo 'hi';
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe your issue a bit more? What are you trying to do? What is happening instead?

Comment: nevermind I figured it out. cheers.

Comment: `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` in this case equals `list&page=1`

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` is equal to the entire query string, i.e. `list&page=1`. You can just use `$_GET['list']` instead:

```
if (isset($_GET['list'])) {
  if ($_GET['page'] == '1') {
    echo 'hi';
  }
}
```

Note: in your example `$_GET['list']` is equal to the empty string, so we use `isset`. BTW you should probably do that for the page variable too, because it might not always be present. In other words, `if ( isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == '1' )`